# If it's weekdays / On weekdays - the same here?

Tags: sentence-construction

Q : How do you decide what to wear?
A :  It depends on the day.

> 1. If it's weekdays, I wear comfortable clothes.
> 2. On weekdays, I wear comfortable clothes.
> 3. If It's on weekdays, I wear comfortable clothes.

I think #2 is perfectly suitable but I'm not sure If #1,3 are the same meaning and possible to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, #2 is correct as written.  #1 and #3 have problems with singular/plural agreement.

For #1, we would talk about a single weekday since you're using the singular pronoun.

> If it's **a** weekday, I wear comfortable clothes.

You could set up a situation in which plural days were being discussed and the sentence would begin "If they're weekdays, ..." That would work, but that is far less likely than the singular version you've presented, and it feels awkward to say it that way.

#3 has the same issue as #1 in terms of singular/plural agreement, but it would be much more comfortable to transform into the plural form than the #1 because of the word *on*.

> Q: What do you wear to (a) meeting(s) with clients who are also friends?
>   
>  
>   A1: If it's on a weekday, I wear comfortable clothes.
>   A2: If they're on weekdays, I wear comfortable clothes.